# What is the least time complex pandas technique to change a df based on other values in the df?

Tags: python, pandas, big-o

I have a df containing 3.5 million entries (rows) of data scraped from the web. One website results in clean data, the other doesn't. I want to replace the brand, category, series of all company M articles, if these articles are in company R. But the code is running way to long. What's the least time complex pandas solution to do so?

```
import pandas as pd
    
d = {
    'company': [
        'R', 
        'R',
        'M',
        'M',
        'M',
        'G'
        ],
    'article': [
        'a',
        'b',
        'a',
        'a',
        'c',
        'a'
         ],
    'brand': [
        'brand1',
        'brand1',
        'brand1x',
        'brand1x',
        'brand1x',
        'brand'
        ],
    'category':[
        'cat',
        'cat',
        'catx',
        'catx',
        'catx',
        'cat'
        ],
    'series':[
        'series1',
        'series1',
        'series1x',
        'series1x',
        'series1x',
        'series'
        ],
    'price':[
        2,
        2.2,
        2.25,
        2.27,
        2.27,
        '',
        ],
    'date':[
        '2023-11-05',
        '2023-11-11',
        '2023-11-05',
        '2023-11-11',
        '2023-11-11',
        ''
        ],
    }
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#create a new df containing only company R-data without duplicates
selected_columns = df[df['company'] == 'R'][['article', 'brand', 'category', 'series']].drop_duplicates()

#Function to update brand,category and series, if article 
def update_values(row):
    article = row['article']
    if article in selected_columns['article'].values:
        selected_row = selected_columns[selected_columns['article'] == article]
        row['brand'] = selected_row['brand'].values[0]
        row['category'] = selected_row['category'].values[0]
        row['series'] = selected_row['series'].values[0]
    return row

#Use function on part M
new = df[df['company'] == 'M'].apply(update_values, axis=1)

#Filter df for R
df = df[df['company'] == 'R']

#Concat both
frames = [new,df]
df = pd.concat(frames)
```

Should follow:

```
d = {
    'company': [
        'R', 
        'R',
        'M',
        'M',
        'M',
        'G'
        ],
    'article': [
        'a',
        'b',
        'a',
        'a',
        'c',
        'a'
         ],
    'brand': [
        'brand1',
        'brand1',
        'brand1',
        'brand1',
        'brand1x',
        'brand'
        ],
    'category':[
        'cat',
        'cat',
        'cat',
        'cat',
        'catx',
        'cat'
        ],
    'series':[
        'series1',
        'series1',
        'series1',
        'series1',
        'series1x',
        'series'
        ],
    'price':[
        2,
        2.2,
        2.25,
        2.27,
        2.27,
        '',
        ],
    'date':[
        '2023-11-05',
        '2023-11-11',
        '2023-11-05',
        '2023-11-11',
        '2023-11-11',
        ''
        ],
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
m = df['company'].eq('M')
df.loc[m, list(selected_columns)] = np.repeat(selected_columns, m.sum(), axis=0)
```

Another option [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
selected_columns = df[df['company'] == 'R'][['article', 'brand', 'category', 'series']].drop_duplicates()

out = (df[['company']].merge(selected_columns.assign(company='M'), how='left')
       .reindex_like(df)
       .fillna(df)
      )
```

If you have companies other than R/M:

```
out = (df.loc[df['company'].eq('M'), ['company']]
       .reset_index()
       .merge(selected_columns.assign(company='M'), how='left')
       .set_index('index').reindex_like(df)
       .fillna(df)
      )
```

Output:

```
  company article   brand category   series price        date
0       R       a  brand1      cat  series1   2.0  2023-11-05
1       R       a  brand1      cat  series1   2.2  2023-11-11
2       M       a  brand1      cat  series1  2.25  2023-11-05
3       M       a  brand1      cat  series1  2.25  2023-11-11
```

Answer (score 0):

in that case, you can use the below approach. This one uses dictionaries to update values. We are creating three dictionaries here. One for each column you want to change. We are then updating values of columns based on company column as the key.

Note that the value of company-brand, company-category and company-series should be unique. For example company R cant have two different brand names. Similarly it cant have more than one category names.

```
new_df_alt=new_df[['company','brand','category','series']].loc[new_df['company']=="R"].copy(deep=True)
new_df_alt['company']="M"

new_df['brand']=new_df['company'].map(brand_dict).fillna(new_df['brand'])
new_df['category']=new_df['company'].map(category_dict).fillna(new_df['category'])
new_df['series']=new_df['company'].map(series_dict).fillna(new_df['series'])
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there a Way to store replaced values and use this information to replace other articles? Like (Company M | Article A | Brand 1x | Series 1x | Category 1x) got replaced by (Company M | Article A | Brand 1 | Series 1 | Category 1) -> replace all (Brand 1x | Series 1x | Category 1x) by (Brand 1 | Series 1 | Category 1)

Comment: You can put the below line of code immediately after merge. It will essentially save all rows eligible for replacement as it is.
stored_df=final_df.loc[final_df['brand_r'].notnull()][['company', 'article', 'brand', 'category' ,'series',  'price' , 'date', 'idx']]

Comment: The solution does only work for articles in equal numbers, like two in R and two in M. Above is the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
It tries removing loops and tries vectorize your operation :

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'company': ['R', 'R', 'M', 'M'],
    'article': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
    'brand': ['brand1', 'brand1', 'brand1x', 'brand1x'],
    'category': ['cat', 'cat', 'catx', 'catx'],
    'series': ['series1', 'series1', 'series1x', 'series1x'],
    'price': [2, 2.2, 2.25, 2.25],
    'date': ['2023-11-05', '2023-11-11', '2023-11-05', '2023-11-11'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Create a mapping for articles from company R
article_mapping = df[df['company'] == 'R'][['article', 'brand', 'category', 'series']].drop_duplicates()

# Use merge to replace values for company M
df.loc[df['company'] == 'M', ['brand', 'category', 'series']] = df.loc[df['company'] == 'M'].merge(
    article_mapping, on='article', how='left', suffixes=('_original', '')
)[['brand', 'category', 'series']].values

# Filter df for company R and remove duplicate rows
df = df[df['company'] == 'R'].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Additionally, if you are further interested in improving, may be you can think of using 'swifter' library : [https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter]